# What is the meaning of the word KOS in the conquestadores stirrup shoe?

Tags: etimología

Most of the brass Conquistadores Stirrups sold in eBay probably are simple and cheap imitates, even if they have been created as worn out shoes with lots of repairs. I remember the stirrup shoes my mother acquired around 1960 in Caracas, Venezuela were also worn out and repaired.

The puzzling thing however was an decorative inscription “KOS” which may have identified the owner or the troops of the stirrups. In the web some similar “KOS”-pairs of shoes marked KOS, but no explanation is given for the inscription.
"KOS Conquistador" is also referred to a song “Procol Harum – Conquistador”, but no explanation is being given.

In Spanish “K”-words are rather seldom. The only words that start with the letter K in Spanish are borrowed words like kilometer, kilowatt, kilogram and kiosk.

That's why this question is posted in the forum.

Click for a sample at:
http://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/pair-antique-kos-conquistador-brass-shoe-stirrups

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre que pueda ser algún acrónimo en latín de alguna oración (por el Kirie eleison) o que sea Kappa Omega Sigma. En ambos casos ni idea.

Comment: It seems this question has been taken from here: [Memories of Venezuela](http://www.scribd.com/doc/109504600/Memories-of-Venezuela)

Answer (score 2):

KOS, es un acrónimo de;

**KOS** - **K**aballero de la **O**rden de **S**antiago

---

Aunque la Orden de Santiago nació en la península ibérica, lo cierto es que mantuvo su lucha y tras la expulsión de los musulmanes tuvo un papel protagonista en el descubrimiento y la conquista del continente americano.

Estos "**K**aballeros de la **O**rden de **S**antiago" participaron en numerosas campañas a lo largo de América durante el siglo XVI.

El primer Santiago de América fue Santiago de los caballeros, en República Dominicana, llamado así ya que la leyenda cuenta que sus primeros pobladores fueron treinta caballeros de la Orden de Santiago el Mayor.

Muchos de los conquistadores españoles eran Caballeros de esta Orden de Santiago, entre ellos encontramos a Hernán Cortés, Francisco Pizarro, Pedro de Alvarado y Contreras, Hernando de Soto y Gutiérrez Cardeñosa, entre otros. También otros descubridores como Fernando Magallanes.

---

La palabra caballero, "kaballero", aparece en numerosos libros de narraciones épico-caballerescas y otras gloriosas batallas que se encuentran redactadas en español antiguo.

[image]

[image]

---

Igualmente podemos encontrar la palabra "KOS" sobre el retrato que aparece de "Francisco Pizarro (1478-1541)", en; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Pizarro , y que hace referencia a la Orden de Santiago, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_Santiago , ya que Francisco Pizarro fue "KOS" (Kaballero de la Orden de Santiago), es decir, un soldado que perteneció y luchó junto con esta Orden de Caballería.

Quien sabe si alguno de estos estribos perteneció a uno de estos conquistadores.

Comment: Excelente investigación. Solucionaste un acertijo que estuvo empolvado por 10 años.

Comment: Gracias por la felicitación.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es una unidad de medida de distancia, puede que apropiada para indicarte que puedes caminar una barbaridad con esos zapatos.

a unit of land distance of various lengths from 1 to 3 miles (1.6 to 4.8 km). http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kos

kos: Milla en mogol, equivalente a unos 4 kilómetros. Esta medida se sigue utilizando en remotas regiones de la India rural
http://www.indiga.org/gloss/gfamily.php?gtype=i

Esta la veo menos probable:

Kós (kŏs, kôs), Lat. Cos, island (1991 pop. 26,379), 111 sq mi (287 sq km), SE Greece, in the Aegean Sea; 2d largest of the Dodecanese, near the Bodrum peninsula of Turkey. Although it rises to c.2,870 ft (875 m) in the southeast, the island is mostly low-lying. Fishing, sponge diving, and tourism are important industries. Grain, tobacco, olive oil, and wine are produced, and cattle, horses, and goats are raised. Kós has mineral deposits and several sulfur springs. The island's main town is Kós (1991 pop. 14,714), situated on the northeast shore. In ancient times the island was controlled in turn by Athens, Macedon, Syria, and Egypt. A cultural center, it was the site of a school of medicine founded in the 5th cent. B.C. by Hippocrates. Kós later enjoyed great prosperity as a result of its alliance with the Ptolemaic dynasty of Egypt, which valued the island as a naval base. The island became part of modern Greece in 1947.

Ya en la Biblia se menciona este lugar: 
Los Hechos

Capítulo 21
21:1 Después de separarnos de ellos, zarpamos y fuimos con rumbo directo a **Cos**, y al día siguiente a Rodas, y de allí a Pátara. 
http://www.amen-amen.net/RV1960/
Tambien Hipócrates era de Cos   http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip%C3%B3crates

Read more: http://www.answers.com/topic/kos#ixzz2BtBM4nyZ

Aqui se hace referencia a los dos significados: Also called coss
 http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Kos
aquí tambien la isla y la unidad de medida indú: http://diccionario.reverso.net/ingles-definiciones/kos

Y aqui: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/kos

Como acrónimo no aparece registrado aquí nada que me parezca pueda asociarse: http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/KOS

Ni aquí: http://www.acronymfinder.com/KOS.html

Ni aqui: http://www.acronymgeek.com/KOS

Conlusión: No es un acrónimo, **Es una unidad de medida que se utiliza en la India.** y que por cierto tiene diferentes valores para diferentes localidades. http://www.definitions.net/definition/KOS